# Understanding and giving an interpretation in the context of First-Order Logic

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

Working on P.D. Magnus. forallX: an Introduction to Formal Logic (pp. 267, exercise A. 1), asks:

Show that each of the following is neither a validity nor a
contradiction:

$D(a) \wedge D(b)$

Do I need to bind $a$ and $b$ to elements of a domain ?

What's an interpretation in this context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One usually only speaks of "binding" in the case of variables getting bound by quantifiers. $a$ and $b$ are names. As specified on p. 248, an interpretation assigns to each name an object from the domain.

So what you have to do is finding one pair of a domain and an assignment of $a$ and $b$ to objects from that domain such that $D(a) \land D(b)$ gets false (to refute validity), and one domain + interpretation such that it gets true (to refute contradictoriness).

Comment: Thank you, @lemontree. Sorry, did you mean that I need to find:

1. one domain + interpretation such that $D(a) \wedge D(b)$ gets true, and
2. one domain + interpretation such that $D(a) \wedge D(b)$ gets false.
Is this correct ?

Comment: Yes, that was a typo and what you said is what I meant; fixed the typo now.

Comment: Can I ask you something ? I am reviewing this chapter and one question arose. As two names (_a_ and _b_) are used, does it mean the domain must contain _at least_ two distinct elements?

Comment: @F. Zer No, two names may be mapped by the interpretation function to the same object.

Comment: Thank you, @lemontree ! So, If I have a domain: {1} and five names: a, b, c, d, e, each of those names could be mapped to 1 ? The number of names used has no relationship with the cardinality of the domain.

Comment: @F. Zer Yes, correct.

Comment: There is also no requirement for every object to have a name.

Comment: Thanks for you last comment, @lemontree ! I also wondered about that.